# C# join dictionaries, with additional information

Tags: c#, dictionary, join

I have no problem joining simple dictionaries, this code works fine:

```
        Dictionary<string, int> lala01 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        lala01.Add("A", 5);
        lala01.Add("B", 2);
        lala01.Add("C", 8);

        Dictionary<string, int> lala02 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        lala02.Add("A", 1);
        lala02.Add("B", 9);
        lala02.Add("X", 4);

        Dictionary<string, int> lala03 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        lala03.Add("A", 7);
        lala03.Add("C", 4);
        lala03.Add("X", 1);
        lala03.Add("Q", 2);

        List<Dictionary<string, int>> dictionaries = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
        dictionaries.Add(lala01);
        dictionaries.Add(lala02);
        dictionaries.Add(lala03);

        var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                     .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                     .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Max());
```

But now I want to add additional information... a string stating from which dictionary the value originated.

The setup:

```
        Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>> lala01 = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        lala01.Add("A", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(5, "lala01"));
        lala01.Add("B", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "lala01"));
        lala01.Add("C", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(8, "lala01"));

        Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>> lala02 = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        lala02.Add("A", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "lala02"));
        lala02.Add("B", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(9, "lala02"));
        lala02.Add("X", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(4, "lala02"));

        Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>> lala03 = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        lala03.Add("A", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(7, "lala03"));
        lala03.Add("C", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(4, "lala03"));
        lala03.Add("X", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "lala03"));
        lala03.Add("Q", new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "lala03"));

        List<Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>> dictionaries = new List<Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>>();
        dictionaries.Add(lala01);
        dictionaries.Add(lala02);
        dictionaries.Add(lala03);
```

Now to get the result, this is where it becomes interesting:

```
        var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                     .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
                     //Basically I am clueless here  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Select(x => x).Max(x => x.Key));
```

**What should I code to include only the keyvaluepair with the max integer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the max by value pair, you are probably looking for something like MaxBy (from [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs)).

```
 var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict)
              .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
              .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.MaxBy(v=> v.Key));
```

If you can't use more linq you could do an `OrderBy` with a `First`

```
 var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict)
              .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
              .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.OrderByDescending(v=> v.Key).First());
```

Comment: If the ordering is by Key than this is the answer! Thank you!